# What's the use of elementlocatorFactory in selenium pagefactory with some real syntax

Tags: selenium, page-factory

I am a new learner, please help me what is the use of elementlocatorFactory in selenium pagefactory .i tried to understand from document which its difficult to understand.

Please help me understand with simple example

Though there are duplicate to the elementlocatorFactory for understanding purposes I create new question
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914570/how-to-implement-ajaxelementlocatorfactory-through-selenium-and-page-factory/54925861#54925861) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874868/what-is-the-difference-between-implicit-wait-and-ajaxelementlocatorfactory/58876172#58876172) discussion helps you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My intention is to understand the use of elementlocatorFactory and fieldlocator. The discussion suggested was from ajaxloadtimeout which I already knew it. Please help me if u have any other reference

Comment: @Learnfever Do you still look for the answer? If yes, contact me (read my profile)